# match 2 arrays and get values

Tags: php, arrays

so there will be 2 arrays. One is fixed:

```
$array1 =     "Animation" => "Animācija/Multfilmas",
"Multiplication" => "Animācija/Multfilmas",
"Action" => "Asa sižeta filmas",
"Detective" => "Detektīvs",
"Documentary" => "okumentālās filmas",
"Drama" => "Drāma",
"Adventure" => "Piedzīvojumu filmas",
"Comedy" => "Komēdija",
"Crime" => "Trilleris",
"Thriller" => "Trilleris",
"Fantasy" => "Fantastika / Sci-Fi",
"Sci-Fi" => "Fantastika / Sci-Fi",
"Family" => "Ģimenes filmas",
"History" => "Vēsturiskas filmas",
"Horror" => "Šausmu filmas",
"Musical" => "Mūzikls",
"Music" => "Mūzikls",
"Romance" => "Romantika",
"Mystery" => "Mistērija",
"Sport" => "Sports",
"Western" => "Vesterns",
"War" => "Kara filmas"
```

and second one will contain something different each time, let me give 2 random examples of what it can contain:

```
$array2 = "War", "Western", "Romance"
```

or

```
$array2 = "Comedy", "Drama"
```

OK, so the idea is to make a function that changes "Comedy" to Komēdija etc (translating)
and if on the end there are 2 identic values, make it one, because Crime and Thriller both are being translated as Trilleris, so if a movie has both genres it will show up as Trilleris, Trilleris once translated and thats kinda stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function translate($words, $dictionary)
{
    $return = array();
    foreach($words as $word)
    {
        $return[ $dictionary[$word] ] = $dictionary[$word];
    }

    return $return;
}
```

$dictionary is the big array while $words is the array containing the words to translate

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Key values on the set array to find and translate the array that needs to be translated.

```
$translated = array();

function translate($array){
    foreach($array as $arr){
        if(array_key_exists($arr, $array1){
           array_push($translated, $array1[$arr]);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($translated);
```

**EDIT:** Changed typo in array_push